How to scroll to the selected Item on GtkListView?
I want to use the GtkListView widget on my app. I've added some items to it. And, I have set an item as the default selected item of the GtkListView. But the problem is, while running the app, I can't automatically scroll to the default selected item. Can anybody check it please?
The demo script is given below ---
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static void
setup_cb (GtkSignalListItemFactory *self, GtkListItem *listitem, gpointer user_data)             
{
  GtkWidget *lb = gtk_label_new (NULL);
  gtk_list_item_set_child (listitem, lb);
}

static void
bind_cb (GtkSignalListItemFactory *self, GtkListItem *listitem, gpointer user_data) {
  GtkWidget *lb = gtk_list_item_get_child (listitem);
  GtkStringObject *strobj = gtk_list_item_get_item (listitem);
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (lb), gtk_string_object_get_string (strobj));
}

static void
scroll_set(GtkListView *listview, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkScrollInfo *scrinfo = gtk_scroll_info_new ();
  gtk_scroll_info_set_enable_vertical ((GtkScrollInfo *)scrinfo, TRUE);
  gtk_list_view_scroll_to ((GtkListView *)listview, 10, GTK_LIST_SCROLL_FOCUS, scrinfo); //avilable 4.12
}


static void
app_activate (GApplication *application) {
  GtkApplication *app = GTK_APPLICATION (application);
  GtkWidget *win = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (win), 200, 100);
  GtkWidget *scr = gtk_scrolled_window_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (win), scr);

  char *array[] = {
    "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ,"six"," seven", 
    "eight" ,"nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",NULL
  };

  GtkWidget *lv = gtk_list_view_new(NULL,NULL); 

  GtkStringList *sl =  gtk_string_list_new ((const char * const *) array);
  GtkSingleSelection *selection = gtk_single_selection_new(G_LIST_MODEL(sl));
  gtk_single_selection_set_autoselect(selection, TRUE);
  gtk_list_view_set_model(GTK_LIST_VIEW(lv),GTK_SELECTION_MODEL(selection));

  GtkListItemFactory *factory = gtk_signal_list_item_factory_new ();
  g_signal_connect (factory, "setup", G_CALLBACK (setup_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (factory, "bind", G_CALLBACK (bind_cb), NULL);

  gtk_list_view_set_factory (GTK_LIST_VIEW (lv),factory);
  gtk_single_selection_set_selected ((GtkSingleSelection *)selection, 10);

  gtk_widget_set_visible(lv, TRUE);
  /*scroll_set cb not working*/
  g_signal_connect (lv, "show", G_CALLBACK (scroll_set), NULL);

  gtk_scrolled_window_set_child (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scr), lv);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkApplication *app;
  int stat;
  app = gtk_application_new ("com.gtk.listview.test", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (app_activate), NULL);
  stat =g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);
 return stat;
}

Note: Here item number 10 is set as selected item. While running the app, to the item number 10 is not scrolling.

Just add a printf in your scroll_set callback function. You'll find that it never called!

Yes, I noticed that. Not getting any solution.

Many of your type-casts are un-necessary.

Is this the root cause of the problem? Can you please tell me where the problem is?
I am testing these; So many things have to be edited. I added the type casting to avoid error massage.

Typecasts are not the root cause, But most of them in your code is redundant. e.g. in scroll_set callback function, scrinfo's type is GtkScrollInfo *. So you don't need to cast it to (GtkScrollInfo *) in gtk_scroll_info_set_enable_vertical call. In the next line, cast to (GtkListView *) is redundant, since listview is GtkListView *. I'll review and debug your code later today hopefully.

If you are new-comer to GTK and Gnome, I suggest using Workbench and prototype your GTK app with a high level language first.

Here is slightly changed application in Python:
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_list_item_factory_setup(signal_list_item_factory, objekt):
    objekt.set_child(Gtk.Label())

def on_list_item_factory_bind(signal_list_item_factory, objekt):
    objekt.get_child().set_label(objekt.get_item().get_string())

def on_selection_model_selection_changed(selection_model, position, n_items, user_data):
    list_view = user_data
    scroll_info = Gtk.ScrollInfo.new()
    scroll_info.set_enable_vertical(True)
    list_view.scroll_to(selection_model.get_selected(), Gtk.ListScrollFlags.FOCUS, scroll_info)

def on_spin_button_value_changed(spin_button, user_data):
    selection_model = user_data
    selection_model.set_selected(spin_button.get_value_as_int() - 1)

def on_application_activate(app):
    arr = [
        'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ,'six',' seven', 
        'eight' ,'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen'
    ]

    window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=app)
    window.set_default_size(200, 100)

    header_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar.new()
    window.set_titlebar(header_bar)

    adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment.new(1, 1, len(arr), 1, 1, 1)
    spin_button = Gtk.SpinButton.new(adjustment, 0, 0)
    header_bar.pack_end(spin_button)

    scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow.new()
    window.set_child(scrolled)

    list_model = Gtk.StringList.new(arr)
    selection_model = Gtk.SingleSelection.new(list_model)
    selection_model.set_autoselect(True)
    spin_button.connect('value_changed', on_spin_button_value_changed, selection_model)

    list_item_factory = Gtk.SignalListItemFactory.new()
    list_item_factory.connect('setup', on_list_item_factory_setup)
    list_item_factory.connect('bind', on_list_item_factory_bind)

    list_view = Gtk.ListView.new(selection_model, list_item_factory)
    selection_model.connect('selection-changed', on_selection_model_selection_changed, list_view)

    scrolled.set_child(list_view)

    window.present()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = Gtk.Application(application_id='com.example.ScrollTestApp')
    app.connect('activate', on_application_activate)

    app.run(sys.argv)

and its C version:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
on_list_item_factory_setup (GtkSignalListItemFactory *item_factory, GObject* objekt, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkListItem *list_item = GTK_LIST_ITEM (objekt);
  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
  gtk_list_item_set_child (list_item, label);
}

static void
on_list_item_factory_bind (GtkSignalListItemFactory *item_factory, GObject *objekt, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkListItem *list_item = GTK_LIST_ITEM (objekt);
  GtkWidget *label = gtk_list_item_get_child (list_item);
  GtkStringObject *string_object = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (label), gtk_string_object_get_string (string_object));
}

static void
on_selection_model_selection_changed (GtkSelectionModel* selection_model, guint position, guint n_items, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkListView *list_view = GTK_LIST_VIEW (user_data);
  GtkScrollInfo *scroll_info = gtk_scroll_info_new ();
  gtk_scroll_info_set_enable_vertical (scroll_info, TRUE);
  int selected = gtk_single_selection_get_selected (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (selection_model));
  gtk_list_view_scroll_to (list_view, selected, GTK_LIST_SCROLL_FOCUS, scroll_info);
}

static void
on_spin_button_value_changed (GtkSpinButton *spin_button, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkSingleSelection *selection_model = user_data;
  int pos = gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int(spin_button) - 1;
  gtk_single_selection_set_selected (selection_model, pos);
}

static void
on_application_activate (GApplication *application, gpointer user_data)
{
  char *array[] = {
    "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" , "six", "seven", 
    "eight" ,"nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
    NULL
  };

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (GTK_APPLICATION (application));
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 100);

  GtkWidget *header_bar = gtk_header_bar_new ();
  gtk_window_set_titlebar (GTK_WINDOW (window), header_bar);

  GtkAdjustment *adjustment = gtk_adjustment_new (1, 1, G_N_ELEMENTS (array), 1, 1, 1);
  GtkWidget *spin_button = gtk_spin_button_new(adjustment, 0, 0);
  gtk_header_bar_pack_end (GTK_HEADER_BAR (header_bar), spin_button);

  GtkWidget *scrolled = gtk_scrolled_window_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), scrolled);

  GtkStringList *list_model = gtk_string_list_new ((const char * const *) array);
  GtkSingleSelection *selection_model = gtk_single_selection_new (G_LIST_MODEL (list_model));
  gtk_single_selection_set_autoselect(selection_model, TRUE);
  g_signal_connect(spin_button, "value_changed", G_CALLBACK (on_spin_button_value_changed), selection_model);

  GtkListItemFactory *list_item_factory = gtk_signal_list_item_factory_new ();
  g_signal_connect (list_item_factory, "setup", G_CALLBACK (on_list_item_factory_setup), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (list_item_factory, "bind", G_CALLBACK (on_list_item_factory_bind), NULL);

  GtkWidget *list_view = gtk_list_view_new (GTK_SELECTION_MODEL (selection_model), list_item_factory); 
  g_signal_connect(selection_model, "selection-changed", G_CALLBACK (on_selection_model_selection_changed), list_view);

  gtk_scrolled_window_set_child (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled), list_view);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *application = gtk_application_new ("com.example.ScrollTestApp", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (application, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_application_activate), NULL);
  int stat = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (application), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (application);
  return stat;
}

I don't know why on application initialization, some signals not emitted. Needs a GTK expert here to answer. But as you see, the signal system works correctly afterwards.
As you see, for small testing purposes, prototyping in Python, Javascript, even in Vala may help.
EDIT:
In comments, I wrote about early setting the selected row and scrolling to selected row, while GTK does not know widget sizes. Here I added a simple loop after gtk_window_present to ask Gtk to complete all its event handling operations (e.g. calculating sizes, handling input events, drawings, ...), then set the row. It works as intended and list view scrolled correctly and shows selected row:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
on_list_item_factory_setup (GtkSignalListItemFactory *item_factory, GObject* objekt, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkListItem *list_item = GTK_LIST_ITEM (objekt);
  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
  gtk_list_item_set_child (list_item, label);
}

static void
on_list_item_factory_bind (GtkSignalListItemFactory *item_factory, GObject *objekt, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkListItem *list_item = GTK_LIST_ITEM (objekt);
  GtkWidget *label = gtk_list_item_get_child (list_item);
  GtkStringObject *string_object = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (label), gtk_string_object_get_string (string_object));
}

static void
on_selection_model_selection_changed (GtkSelectionModel* selection_model, guint position, guint n_items, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkListView *list_view = GTK_LIST_VIEW (user_data);
  GtkScrollInfo *scroll_info = gtk_scroll_info_new ();
  gtk_scroll_info_set_enable_vertical (scroll_info, TRUE);
  int selected = gtk_single_selection_get_selected (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (selection_model));
  gtk_list_view_scroll_to (list_view, selected, GTK_LIST_SCROLL_FOCUS, scroll_info);
}

static void
on_application_activate (GApplication *application, gpointer user_data)
{
  char *array[] = {
    "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" , "six", "seven", 
    "eight" ,"nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
    NULL
  };

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (GTK_APPLICATION (application));
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 100);

  GtkWidget *scrolled = gtk_scrolled_window_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), scrolled);

  GtkStringList *list_model = gtk_string_list_new ((const char * const *) array);
  GtkSingleSelection *selection_model = gtk_single_selection_new (G_LIST_MODEL (list_model));
  gtk_single_selection_set_autoselect(selection_model, TRUE);

  GtkListItemFactory *list_item_factory = gtk_signal_list_item_factory_new ();
  g_signal_connect (list_item_factory, "setup", G_CALLBACK (on_list_item_factory_setup), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (list_item_factory, "bind", G_CALLBACK (on_list_item_factory_bind), NULL);

  GtkWidget *list_view = gtk_list_view_new (GTK_SELECTION_MODEL (selection_model), list_item_factory); 
  g_signal_connect(selection_model, "selection-changed", G_CALLBACK (on_selection_model_selection_changed), list_view);

  gtk_scrolled_window_set_child (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled), list_view);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));

  while (g_main_context_pending (g_main_context_default ()))
    g_main_context_iteration (NULL, TRUE);

  gtk_single_selection_set_selected (selection_model, 10);
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *application = gtk_application_new ("com.example.ScrollTestApp", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (application, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_application_activate), NULL);
  int stat = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (application), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (application);
  return stat;
}

Gtk and also its object system, GObject, GType, ... are amazing. I strongly recommend every C developer to study its internals and codes. If you develop Gtk based widgets, libraries, ..., you should learn its internals.

When the app launches, I want it to scroll to the selected item. But the spin button on your script has been used. So automatically scroll on app launch did not happen.. Actually I am trying to create font selection widget. Thank you.

I removed spin button, and added selection_model.set_selected(9) before window.present(). Signal emitted and its callback ran, but scrolling didn't work. I think in this state, size and placement of widgets aren't calculated yet. Best place to get answer for your question is Gtk matrix group where core gtk developers exist there.

Gtk4 Documentation: gtk_list_view_scroll_to -
"This function works no matter if the listview is shown or focused."

A GtkWidget has many states in its lifetime, like realize, map, ...  . I saw that phrase in Gtk doc, but in activate handler, widgets don't reach those states (show, ...) and is not fully created yet. Sizes depend on hierarchical calculations (Gtk needs to know all child widget sizes to calculate parent widget size). We set the focused row and want to scroll to it, but when Gtk doesn't know sizes of the ListView and ScrolledWindow. Read this and this.

I edited my post and added a new program. It works as you wanted.
